# Symfony2 form query crashes

Tags: forms, symfony, query-builder

I have the following statement in a Symfony 2.7.9 FormType form;

```
    $builder
        ->add(
            'team',
            'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'NmsClubBundle:Team',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($club_id) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                        ->where('t.club = :club')
                        ->andWhere('t.active = 1')
                        ->orderBy('t.title', 'ASC')
                        ->setParameter('club', $club_id);
                },
            )
        )
```

In a database with a few records, the select works fine.
In a database with many records, this statement causes the server to crash, even though the query only returns 6 records.

Can anyone provide any guidance on the cause?

Comment: Errors? Crash and say what?

Comment: Chrome displays
No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.

Comment: Wait, chrome? Didn't you say the server crashed?

Comment: Apache stopped sending to Chrome. I've found this in the apache error log, but do not know why it is happening
[Thu Feb 18 20:42:07.933772 2016] [:error] [pid 21681] [client 127.0.0.1:53579] PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of SymfonyBundleMonologBundleSwiftMailerMessageFactory_000000003ffa0969000000017ec3879688655e920717539d4dba74863d3a6372::initializeProxy() must be compatible with ProxyManager\\Proxy\\LazyLoadingInterface::initializeProxy(): bool in /Users/paul/Sites/b3/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 2077, referer: http://b3.dev/app_dev.php/comp/nomination/8856/edit

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to have anything to do with your code. The error is from the e-mailer service and not your DB query.

Comment: The last line shows the connection
b3.dev/app_dev.php/comp/nomination/8856/edit 
is the URL that is being called.
I have memory set at 256Mb max. I suspect that memory has been exceeded and these services cannot load.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution, but still do not know the cause.
Increased memory available to PHP to 1024Mb. Same result. Set memory back to 256Mb.
I moved the query into the controller and passed an array of objects into the FormType. The Form builder looks like this

```
        $builder
        ->add('team', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'NmsClubBundle:Team',
            'choices' => $teams,
        ))
```

Same problem.
So I went back to the controller and created an array of (index => name) from the array of objects. Then changed the Form builder to look like this

```
        $builder
        ->add('team', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $teams,
            'label' => 'Teams',
            'data' => key($teams),
            'mapped' => false,
        ))
```

This works.